# Swift Extensions Best Practices

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've recently gotten addicted to `Extensions`. One thing I've found to be a gigantic PITA is figuring where I stashed a useful method for something like an `Array`, an `NSManagedObject`, etc.

What I've done is put my extensions in an `NSObject` class file called `CustomExtensions` and I list the Class Extensions there in alphabetical order.

It works, but I want to see if it aligns with best practices. If not, what is the best way to track `Extensions`?

Here's what I've done:

```
class CustomExtensions: NSObject {
    /*
     Useful extensions, nothing else here
     */
}
// Example extension    
extension Int {
    func formatAsTimeString() -> String {
        let seconds = self % 60
        let minutes = (self / 60) % 60
        let hours = self / 3600
        let stringHours = hours > 9 ? String(hours) : "0" + String(hours)
        let stringMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes) : "0" + String(minutes)
        let stringSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : "0" + String(seconds)

        if hours > 0 {
            return "\(stringHours):\(stringMinutes):\(stringSeconds)"
        }
        else {
            return "\(stringMinutes):\(stringSeconds)"
        }
    }
}
// More extensions below
```

Comment: What do you mean that you put your extensions *in* an `NSObject`? An `Array` extension should not be *in* any other class for example...

Comment: @DanielT. Thanks for reading. I updated my answer so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Based on your example, I still don't understand what this `CustomExtensions` class is supposed to be for. Surely you don't sub-class off of it, do you?

Comment: I just created a blank `NSObject` class and threw extensions at the bottom of it so they're all in one place, rather than scattered throughout a bunch of different files. This approach works for me, but I wanted to see if it aligns with best practices.

Comment: If the `CustomExtensions` class is empty, then get rid of it. It is wholly unnecessary. I'm composing an answer to your question now...

Comment: Why don't you just put them in a swift file? Just import UIKit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the "best practices" around this issue have been figured out yet. That said, here is MHO:

Ultimately, I treat these extensions the same way I do global functions in C. After all, that's basically what they are. Global functions with a special syntax...

If the extension is only used in one file, then I will put the extension in the same file. I end up with quite a few of these by the time I'm done. For example, your `formatAsTimeString` is a view model kind of thing. If it is used by a single view controller, I would leave it in the view controller's file.

If the extension is used by multiple classes, then I will break it out into a separate file. I will name the file after the extension. So for example if the `formatAsTimeString` is used in multiple files, then I will have a file named something like, "Int+formatAsTimeString.swift" where the extension can live.

If there are a number of related functions, then I will put them together in the same file and name the file based on the abstract idea of the functions. I decide that the functions are related by imagining whether they would all have to be moved together if I choose to use them in a different program... For example, maybe I have other time string related functions...

Comment: Awesome thought. I started using this methodology to retrieve `UserDefault` values within an app and I started throwing other stuff in there. Before I run to far doing things this way, I wanted to get some input. Thank you for your thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 3):

With Swift3, I generally tend to use 'fileprivate' if the extension is only used in one file.

```
fileprivate extension Date
{
    func toString( dateFormat format  : String ) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to have good "official" guidelines on this! But as mentioned people are figuring this out as we go along.

**ViewController-Extensions**

An interesting use I have found is the in-file extensions for a more complex class, like a ViewController.

Instead of going:

```
public class MainViewController: UIViewController, SpecialDelegate {
  // functions
}
```

You can spread each import into its own extension:

```
public class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  // functions
}

extension MainViewController: SpecialDelegate {
  // functions
}
```

These effectively serve as easier formatting, and can make it much easier to organize extended classes, especially with very large classes/projects. Note that these should stay in the same file, or at the least in a file right next to the main one.

**Simple added functionality**

For simple extensions like this:

```
extension Int {
  /**
   Returns true when the integer is even.
   */
  var isEven: Bool {
    return self % 2 == 0
  }
}
```

I usually have a folder labeled `extensions` where I keep all of the extension files. I have witnessed more complicated projects having the files more closely to where they are used, but I disagree with that usage.

After all, extensions are supposed to be used throughout the project, hiding them makes it more difficult to find if a certain extension already exists.

**Highly specialized functionality**

As mentioned in other replies here it makes sense to create a fileprivate extension for use-cases that will not be used elsewhere, and put in into the file where it is used

```
fileprivate extension String {
  // Highly specialized function that will NEVER be used anywhere else
}
```

**Extension Naming**

I have noticed various types of writing out extension-files. When I started out doing iOS-dev the prevailing guideline was to write `String-Extension.swift`. Nowadays `String+Extension.swift` seems to have won out.

In addition to that a lot of people write the name of the added functionality to the file, like `Int+IsEven.swift`, but that is only useful if there is a single function per file.